# Dividing data.frames, stored in a list, into equal parts

Tags: r

The following code creates a list with two data frames.

```
tzu <- c(1:110)
tzu1 <- c(1:110)

df1 <- data.frame(tzu, tzu1)

atu <- c(1:120)
atu1 <- c(1:120)

df2 <- data.frame(atu, atu1)
n <- list(df1, df2)
```

I would like to divide the first data frame (n[[1]]) into 11 equal parts and the second one into 12 equal parts. (See object: parts). The following code is to split the data frames, unfortunately it only works when the list is converted to a df. In my example there are now only two dfs in a list but in the original data there will be up to 200, so it would be really great to automate this "mechanism" so that the first df (n[[1]]) is split with the first value of parts, the second (n[[2]]) with the second value and so on.

```
 parts <- c(11,12)
 max <- parts
 x <- seq_along(n[[1]])
 d1 <- split(n[[1]], ceiling(x/max))
```

Unfortunately, somehow it does not work. The object n[[1]] is not split as desired and so on.

Comment: If you need 11 and 12 parts, shouldn't this be divided by 10

Comment: You got right, I phrased it wrong. I have to divide it trough 11 and so I get 11 equal parts etc. With parts I mean the number with which it should be divided. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `split` with `gl` by dividing the number of rows by the corresponding value in 'parts after looping over the `list` with `Map`

```
out <-  Map(function(x, y) split(x, as.integer(gl(nrow(x), 
      nrow(x)/y, nrow(x)))), n, parts)
```

-checking

```
lengths(out)
[1] 11 12
```

Comment: @Selina1 I initially, thought you wanted `Map(function(x, y) split(x, as.integer(gl(nrow(x), y, nrow(x)))), n, parts)`, but this would split into less than 11 or 12 parts

Comment: The only thing is now, I have a list with 100dfs and the first df I need to splitted in 11 equal parts, the next is 12, and the next is 31, after this 27.... Is it possible to implement in your solution a vector like "parts" which contains the numbers ? Like parts <- c(11,12,31,27,56,2) and so on. So that the first df get divided by 11, the next by 12, the third by 31 and so on?

Comment: @Selina1 Can you try the update in my post

Comment: That's it! This is perfect. I tested it with different numbers and it works :-) A big thank you for your help!!! Now I will test it on my original data. I let you know if it works there too.

Answer (score 2):

**Upate:**
For use of multiple df's in list we could use:
`map` from  `purrr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
n_result <- n %>%
    map(~mutate(., id = as.integer(gl(n(), nrow(.)/10, n())))) %>% 
    map(~group_split(., id))

glimpse(n_result)
```

Output:

```
List of 2
 $ : list<tibble[,3]> [1:10] 
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [11 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..@ ptype: tibble [0 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ : list<tibble[,3]> [1:10] 
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ : tibble [12 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..@ ptype: tibble [0 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
```

**First answer**:
We could use `group_split` after adding an `id` of 11 in `df1` and 12 in `df2`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1_list <- n[[1]] %>% 
    mutate(id = as.integer(gl(n(), 11, n()))) %>% 
    group_split(id)
    
df2_list <- n[[2]] %>% 
    mutate(id = as.integer(gl(n(), 12, n()))) %>%
    group_split(id)

n_splitted <- (list(df1_list, df2_list))
```

Comment: That's very nice from you, but so I have to do it over 200 times... always put in the number by hand, is there no other solution ? Or do I misunderstand your solution?

Comment: Oh I see. Please see my update. I have not noticed the info in your question, sorry for that!

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution! :-) I appreciate it.